# How To Implement a Safari Browser Plugin?

Tags: safari, plugins, browser-history

I want to implement a Safari plugin under OS X that manages the browsing history in an alternative way. More precisely, i need to have access to data like "a link is clicked", where the link leads and on which page the clicked link is located. In addition to that, i need to draw a representation of the gathered data. I want it to feel as native as possible and i do not prefer any language/framework etc. for this project.

What are my options? I just need a point to start from, because i have never built a browser plugin or something similar before. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) a whirl. It'll ease some of the pain.